# Do Call of Cthulhu manuals depend on the core rulebook version?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu

I'm planning to buy a few manuals for Chaosium's Call of Cthulhu, but I can't find anywhere if the other manuals (say e.g. Cthulhu by gaslight) and adventures are strictly tied to an edition or if they can be used without major problems with any one of the seven editions.

I see in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27036/what-are-the-changes-between-editions) that the differences between editions seem to be minor, but there are also cases where a new edition comes with incompatible rules, e.g. D&D, so I'd like to be cautious before I waste money in books I don't need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All CoC adventures can be used without major problems in any of the editions.

Only the most "rulesey" of manuals, like the Investigator's Companion section on new occupations, would be mildly affected, but in reality the game systems are 90%+ identical across all 7 versions.

I have a large library of CoC books and I have never had cause to worry about version differences.

Comment: At most you will have to change skills on NPCs or monsters, something that can easily be done.

Comment: @mxyzplk: Is there a way to distinguish between the most "rulesey" manuals and the others, or at least a list? Maybe simply the date of publishing?

Comment: No, just books that happen to have more rules content - monster books and character occupations mostly.  But really, even with those there's not much.  It's got nothing to do with date.  The question you linked does a more than adequate job of explaining it... CoC's not D&D, you can quit worrying.